Generally, order and other higher taxonomic categories are identified based on the aggregates of characters. Please explain this
In a book it is written: Generally,
order and other higher taxonomic categories are identified based on the aggregates of characters.
What does it means? Every group is made only after observing aggregate of characteristics then why it is said so? This statement can be seen in a standard high school book (NCERT class 11th chapter 1) in India.

Welcome to the Biology Stack Exchange. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information on this site and how it works. What do you think it means? This sounds pretty straightforward to me and we have a homework requirement here.

To rephrase bob1's comment: what do you think it means? or, why doesn't it make sense to you? I agree that the text you show is badly written, but hopefully you can still puzzle out a meaning with some effort, it is not technically complex.

Hi bob1 the statement is straight forward but I have question about aggregate word. Any group form considers many characters. Then why it is written for higher order groups only.
